# In which table MS CRM system views are stored?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking for the table that holds the criteria records for MS Dynamics CRM system views or saved Advanced Find views. 
Every saved view (system view or custom view) has some criteria that are used to filter the results. I would like to find the table in the database that holds this criteria as records.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

System views are stored inside `SavedQuery`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg594431.aspx

User views (saved from Advanced Find) are stored inside `UserQuery`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509053.aspx